# SublimeREPL doesn't work with Javascript code

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimerepl

Recently I installed SublimeREPL from Sublime Text Package Control and didn't change or modify anything else. I have Node.js installed and added its path to the PATH variable so I can run it from Windows Powershell. 
The problem is, whenever I run REPL from sublime I get this:

```
internal/validators.js:113
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "stringToWrite" argument must be of type string. Received type object
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:113:11)
    at REPLServer._writeToOutput (readline.js:321:3)
    at REPLServer.Interface.prompt (readline.js:290:10)
    at REPLServer.displayPrompt (repl.js:973:8)
    at new REPLServer (repl.js:825:8)
    at Object.exports.start (repl.js:843:16)
    at C:\Users\Milad\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeREPL\config\NodeJS\repl.js:5:20
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Milad\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SublimeREPL\config\NodeJS\repl.js:38:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:971:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1011:10) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}

***Repl Closed***
```

What's wrong? I tried with any .js codes I had. The result is the same. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

I tried to run repl by choosing `Node` from `Tools/SublimeREPL` menu. Also, I noticed there's a `Build` option and the `Build System` menu which doesn't include `Node`. I don't know how it works so I didn't touch that.

Comment: The error message seems clear to me: `The "stringToWrite" argument must be of type string. Received type object`

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: "whenever I run REPL from sublime I get this" – so even the simplest bit of JavaScript such as `console.log('test')` will throw the exact same error?

Comment: Yes, it throws the same error.